# What does "Unexpected <import> in schema </import"> mean?

Tags: php, parsing, wsdl, soap-client

I have the following in a wsdl provdided by my service provider:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://web-service-provider.com/2004/10/10" schemaLocation="ASchemas.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://web-service-provider.com/2004/10/10" schemaLocation="BSchemas.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://web-service-provider.com/2004/10/10" schemaLocation="CSchemas.xsd"/>
```

and I get the following error when the SoapClient tries to parse the wsdl:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected <import> in schema</import>
```

What exactly does this mean?

Thanks

#### Notes

The representative url for the various resources are:

wsdl (short url): https://service-provider.com/services/serviceA?wsdl

wsdl (long url): https://service-provider.com/services/serviceA/wsdl/serviceA.wsdl

xsd's: https://service-provider.com/services/serviceA/wsdl/ASchemas.xsd

```
php version: 5.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This from my service provider:

> Your soap client is not resolving the
>   web reference (schema import etc)
>   correctly and causing this problem.
>   Either you need to fix this reference
>   issue on the client side or try a
>   different URL structure or try to
>   parse by removing the schema reference
>   from WSDL if possible

Hmpph. Not happy with that answer